# Fail2ban without proactive mode

Tags: linux, security, firewall, fail2ban

Is there any way to configure Fail2ban to just log suspicious activities without change my firewall rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fail2ban includes a `dummy` banaction which does (almost) nothing. You can try using that as your `banaction`.